# Why Can I Not Create a Picture Password in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, password-management, pictures

Orientation:
PC Settings: 
User
I have no option to create a Picture Password for my user account in Windows 8, what am I doing wrong?  Incidentally, I see no option to create a PIN logon either. 
[image: How to create a picture password?]

[image: Group Policy Setting Workgroup / Homegroup Machine]

**Question:** is this policy setting even relevent as my machine is not part of a domain?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-8/why-create-picture-password

Comment: Are you connected to a domain?

Comment: No domain, just a homegroup.

Comment: Create a new user and see if its there, my guess it won't be, which means its a policy problem.

Comment: In the first screenshot above, the last option says "Any user who has a password doesn't need to enter it when waking this PC"  try changing that so you need a password to wake it.  Does that change anything?  Also, if I understand what you mean by domain, it doesn't matter.  I can (and have) created picture passwords for the Win8 computer I use and it isn't part of a domain.

Comment: I reversed the password setting, but nothing changed regarding Pin or Picture sign on options.

Comment: I am supposing you have seen [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/7665-picture-password-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html) thread?

Answer (score 1):

Googling this problem yields [Why can't I create a picture password?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-8/why-create-picture-password):

> If you don't see this option, your domain or network settings and security policies might be set to prevent you from creating a picture password. For more info, check with your system admin.

Googling further yields [Passwords Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831800.aspx):

> ## Picture password on domain-joined computers.
>
> Picture passwords are not disabled on the domain joined computers by default. The behavior can be configured using GPO System\Logon\Turn off picture password sign-in

You should investigate whether you have Group Policy configured on this setting.

[image]

**EDIT** If you want to check what group policy settings are being applied, run `rsop.msc` from the *Run* menu.

[image]

Comment: I checked, it WAS set to 'Not configured'.  I changed to disabled.  Still no sign of the Picture Password option

Comment: "Still no sign of the Picture Password option" - I'm not surprised, since it clearly states that Not Configured = Disabled.

Comment: @Karan "Not configured" means ... not configured. Multiple group policy objects can apply at once.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: As per the screenshot above, it says "If you *disable* or *don't configure* this policy setting, a domain user can set up and use a picture password." Doesn't that imply that in this case both result in the exact same thing, i.e. Not Configured is as good as setting it to Disabled?

Comment: @Karan Group policy layers. If you look at the local group policy editor and this setting is set to *Not Configured* but there's another group policy object that has this setting set to *Enabled* then you can say *Not Configured = Disabled* all you want, but you won't be able to set a picture password. Although I think that's not particularly applicable in this case because Guy says his PC isn't part of a domain.

Comment: Has anyone setup PIN or picture logon with a NON domain account?  I ask because I have re-read the policy and it's inference is that PIN or picture logons are for domain users.